# Selecting first element of type LESS

Tags: html, css, less

Why can't I choose the first header element with `header:nth-of-type(1)` This is the code but jsfiddle doesn't support less http://jsfiddle.net/0kzgj9fd/. **I need it written with LESS**

I've also tried with `:first-child` and `nth-child(1)` but, unfortunately didn't worked for me ...

Comment: Note that JSFiddle does not directly support Less, so your fiddle is quite useless (to show a Less snippet use either [specially adopted template](http://lesscss.org/usage/#online-less-compilers--jsfiddle-http-jsfiddle-net-hb2rsm2x-), or better use [any other playground](http://lesscss.org/usage/#online-less-compilers-online-web-ides-playgrounds-with-less-support) with native Less support).

Comment: Please add your code to the question - the link to jsfiddle might die.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need the `>` selector to specify it's the immediate child of `#wrapper`

```
    #wrapper {
        background: white;
        height: 100%;
        width: 1720px;
        margin: 0 auto;
        border: 3px solid #707070;

        >header:nth-of-type(1) {
            margin: 0 auto;
            width: 90%;
            height: 200px;
            background: red;
            border: 3px solid #707070;

            h1 {

                color: #707070;
            }

        }
    }
```

Proof: http://jsfiddle.net/T2Xe9/375/

Answer (score 2):

Because you're always an element behind another tag, therefore, it is always the first. Try use ">" as element after element. See. for example

```
#wrapper {
    background: white;
    height: 100%;
    width: 1720px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    border: 3px solid #707070;

    > header:nth-child(1) {
        margin: 0 auto;
        width: 90%;
        height: 200px;
        background: red;
        border: 3px solid #707070;

        h1 {
            color: #707070;
        }
    }
}
```

And good isn't to use so much nesting. The resulting css look bad

```
html body #wrapper > header:child(1) h1 .......
```

better is

```
* {}
html {}
body {}
#wrapper {
    header:nth-of-type(1) {     
        h1 {
        }
    }
}
```